# Custom Type to store and output data

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a project for work where I need to determine a number of values based on the concentration and component inputs. I have used named ranges for the source data. I am looking for advice on how best to call this public function, whether it should be moved to its own module, and how best to output this data. I was thinking of using a nested for loop to print the data stored by the public function (should it be public?) to an output page for each characteristic of the components.

Is this a good approach, will it work, is there a better way?

```
Public Static Function StoreData()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 1
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim Inputs() As Components
    Dim Source_Row As Variant
    Dim Input_Conc As Range
        Set Input_Conc = Worksheets("Input").Range("D3:D52")

    Do ' Counts number of Components
        If IsEmpty(Input_Conc(i)) = False Then
            j = j + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Input_Conc(i)) = True

    ReDim Inputs(j)
    k = 3
    Do
        For i = LBound(Inputs) To UBound(Inputs)
            With Inputs(i)
                .CAS = Worksheets("Input").Cells(k, 3)
                .Concentration = Worksheets("Input").Cells(k, 4)
                .Name = Worksheets("Input").Cells(k, 2)

                .Source_Row = Application.Match(Inputs(i).CAS, Worksheets("Component Properties").Range("A3:A1000"), 0)

                .Name = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 2)
                .MW = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 3)
                .VP50_Kpa = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 4)
                .Tki = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 5)
                .L_Den = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 6)
                .mL_mol = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 7)
                .BP = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 8)
                .FP = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 9)
                .Refrigerated = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 10)
                .Pyrophoric = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 11)
                .GUP = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 12)
                .FG = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 13)
                .LG = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 14)
                .FL = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 15)
                .OG = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 16)
                .SC = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 17)
                .EI = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 18)
                .RS = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 19)
                .SS = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 20)
                .GCM = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 21)
                .Carcinogen = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 22)
                .RH = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 23)
                .STORE = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 24)
                .STOSE = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 25)
                .EHA = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 26)
                .EHC = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 27)
                .ODS = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 28)
                .Toxicity = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 29)
                .AMCRN = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 30)
                .Tci = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 31)
                .LC50 = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 32)
                .S1S = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 33)
                .S2S = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 34)
                .Comp_F = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 35)
                .SL_Hi = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 36)
                .SL_Lo = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 37)
                .Reactive = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 38)
                .BTU = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 39)
                .LEL = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 40)
                .UEL = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 41)
                .MOC = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 42)
                .CF = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 43)
                .KK = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 44)
                .Prop_65 = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 45)
                .C_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 46)
                .H_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 47)
                .O_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 48)
                .S_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 49)
                .Si_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 50)
                .B_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 51)
                .N_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 52)
                .P_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 53)
                .F_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 54)
                .Cl_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 55)
                .Br_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 56)
                .I_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 57)
                .Halogen_no = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 58)
                .Silane = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 59)
                .Amine = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 60)
            End With
            j = j + 1
        Next i
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Inputs(i).CAS) = True
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry about the initial double copy of the code. Thank you for correcting that Mod team

Comment: I should add, I made it clear to my boss that I was not a programmer, so I apologize for my lack of knowledge if this is a common issue.

Comment: You are currently populating a range to many properties.  It would be simpler to have a backing field in the component object that accepts an array and an enumeration with the component object that aloows the correct accing of that array to that you can get back individual properties if that is what is required. Thus you would have input(i).data = Worksheets("Component Properties".range.cells(Source_row:2),cells(source_row,60)).values

Comment: @freeflow I will have to see what you mean by a backing field, I'm not familiar so I'll search around. What does enumeration mean in this context? I will add the .values bit now.

Comment: Don't panic. Full answer on the way.

Comment: @freeflow thanks in advance bud, this has me so stressed right now

Answer (score 1):

I've made some comments on the code provided.  You may be able to use the edited code, but even if you can't it shows some useful stuff.
Naturally I haven't run the code because I don't have access to the the source workbook.

The code to implement the backing variable and enumberation I mentioned in my comment follows the comments on the provided code.

**New To VBA?**

If you are new to programming in VBA then there are four things you can do to make your life less painful.

1. Getting help.  In the VBA Ide, if you place the cursor on a VBA keyword, or Office object and press F1 you will get
   the MS help page for that keyword/Object.
2. Put option explicit at the top of each module/class
3. Do a Dugbug.Compile project before you run any code to make sure
   that all easily spotted syntax errors have been addressed
4. Install the fantastic and free RubberDuck addin for VBA which gives you lots of really useful tools (proper renaming, refactoring, formatting of code etc) especially for the learnings you will get from the Code Ispections utility.  This is a really really important step.
   http://rubberduckvba.com/

I don't routinely use Excel so there may be advice that can be provided by others that will be better than any advice I've provided below regarding Excel

**Static Function**

You have declared a function as static with an implicit return value of Variant but don't actually return anything from the function.

The static keyword preserves the values of all variables local to the function/sub but in a way that they can only be
accessed if you are actually in the function/or sub.  I suspect it is really your intention to  use the Inputs variable
to store information for use elsewhere.  As a consequence I've

- Encapsulated Inputs in a user defined type at module scope and
  added code to allow access to Inputs from outside the module. To do
  this I've removed Static from the function declaration, changed it to
  a submoved the declaration of the Inputs variable out of the function
  to Module scope in a UDT. The references below will help with
  understanding of UDT and what we are doing with variable s.
- changed the function  to a sub as we are now populating a module
  scope variable rather than returning a value
- removed the static keyword because we only want to preserve Inputs
  rather than every variable in the sub (but I acknowledge we may also
  need to do the same for data from the myInputWs

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/type-statement
' https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/25/private-this-as-tsomething/

```
Option Explicit

Private Type State

    Components()                    As Components

End Type

Private s                           As State


Public Function Components() As Variant
    Components = s.Components
End Function


Public Property Set Component(ByVal Index As Long, ByVal Value As Variant)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim dummy As Variant
    dummy = s.Components(0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise 9, "ModuleName:Set Item: s.Inputs has not been initialised£"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    s.Components(Index) = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Component(ByVal Index As Long) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim dummy As Variant
    dummy = s.Components(0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise 9, "ModuleName:Get Item: s.Inputs has not been initialised£"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Component = s.Components(Index)
End Property


Public Sub SetComponentProperties()

    Dim myPropsWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Set myPropsWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.[_Default]("Component Properties")
    Dim myInputWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Set myInputWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.[_Default]("Input")
```

**Don't code something that Excel does better**

You appear to have a section of code that counts non empty cells in a range.  The advice here is that unless you are doing something very specific its better to let
Excel (or other office app) do the heavy lifting.  In your case you can probably use WorksheetFunction to call the CountA excel function. The use of the worksheet function allows us to collapse

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Dim j As Integer
j = 1
Dim k As Integer

Dim Input_Conc As Range
Set Input_Conc = Worksheets("Input").Range("D3:D52")

Do ' Counts number of Components
    If IsEmpty(Input_Conc(i)) = False Then
        j = j + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IsEmpty(Input_Conc(i)) = True

ReDim Inputs(j)
```

to

```
Dim myNonEmptyCells As Long
myNonEmptyCells = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myInputWs.Range("D3:D52"))
ReDim s.Components(myNonEmptyCells)
```

In the above code I've used an intermediate variable to capture the count of cells as this makes debugging easier (e.g. when stepping through code using F8)

**Reuse of variables and unhelpful naming**

You have declared the variables i and j and used them in two different scenarios in your function.  The is a recipe for pain and anguish.  I'd very strongly recommend not reusing variables, no matter how clever or convenient it may seem.  I'd also recommend not using names like i and j. Use proper meaningful names so that in six months time, you or the next unfortunate soul to update the code has a better chance of understanding what the code is doing.

You also seem to have a unused variable 'Source_Row' that matches a property of the Components class '.Source_Row'.  Again this is a recopie for pain and anguish.  I'd use a more informative name for 'Source_Row' e.g. SourceRowInExcel.  Its also worth noting that this variable is not actually used anywhere in the sub which is another difficult point for future reviewers.

**For Each vs For To**

The main loop of your function iterates over the Inputs array but only uses the control variable of the loop (reused i) as an index.  In such a case we can simplify code by using a 'For Each' loop.  For a 'For Each' loop the control variable MUST be a variant or object type.  I'll often set up a separate indexing variable that has to be incremented as +1 to gain the benefits of 'For Each'.

Dim myInput As Variant
For Each myInput In s.Inputs
    
Next

**Making things easier to read**

You clearly have a grasp of the 'With' structure but have probably found that this structure can be frustrating as typically you'd like two 'With' structures to run in parallel.  Consequently its best to avoid the 'With' structure except for simple cases and instead use local variables to provide the needed shortcuts

```
Dim myPropsWs As Excel.Worksheet
Set myPropsWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.[_Default]("Component Properties")
Dim myInputWs As Excel.Worksheet
Set myInputWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.[_Default]("Input")
```

**Unnecessary Work**

The do loop has a test for an empty cell at the end of the loop.  This means that if .Cas is empty you still populate 58 Components values before you exit the sub.  A more sensible approach would be to test for the empty cell at the start of the loop and then do any
adjustment necessary after the loop and before you exit the sub.

```
Dim j As Long: j = 0

Dim myInput As Variant
Dim k As Long: k = 3
Do Until IsEmpty(myInputWs.Cells.Item(k, 3))


    For Each myInput In s.Components

        Set myInput = New Components

        ' The addition of code to deal with data from myInputWs is left as an exercise for the reader
        myInput.Cas = myInputWs.Cells.Item(k, 3)

        myInput.Concentration = myInputWs.Cells.Item(k, 4)
        myInput.Name = myInputWs.Cells.Item(k, 2)
        myInput.Source_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myInput.Cas, myPropsWs.Range("A3:A1000"), 0)


        myInput.ComponentProperties = myPropsWs.Range(myPropsWs.Cells.Item(myInput.Source_Row, 2), myPropsWs.Cells.Item(myInput.Source_Row, 60)).Value2

    Next

    j = j + 1

Loop
```

Alternatively you could have an endless loop with the exit clause based in the loop itself

```
Do

    For Each myInput In s.Inputs


        Set myInput = New Components
        myInputs.Cas = myInputWs.Cells(k, 3)

        If IsEmpty(myInputWs.Cells(k, 3)) Then

            ' any other needed action before exiting
            Exit Function

        End If

        myInput.Concentration = myInputWs.Cells(k, 4)
        myInput.Name = myInputWs.Cells(k, 2)
        myInput.Source_Row = Application.Match(myInput.Cas, myPropsWs.Range("A3:A1000"), 0)

        myInput.ComponentProperties = myPropsWs.Range(myPropsWs.Cells(myInputs.Source_Row, 2), myPropsWs.Cells(myInputs.Source_Row, 60)).Value2

    Next

Loop
```

If it were not for the j=j+1 line, we could dispense with the Do loop altogether, but as j gives us absolutely no clue as to what you are doing at that point I've left it in.

Also, as an aside, in your original code you have two lines assigning different values to the same Components property .Name?.

```
.Name = Worksheets("Input").Cells(k, 2)
.Source_Row = Application.Match(Inputs(i).CAS, Worksheets("Component Properties").Range("A3:A1000"), 0)
.Name = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 2)
```

For ease of use the code to replace your function is provided below

```
Option Explicit

Private Type State

    Components()                    As ScriptingDictionary

End Type

Private s                           As State


Public Function Components() As Variant
    Components = s.Components
End Function


Public Property Set Component(ByVal Index As Long, ByVal Value As Variant)
    If UBound(s.Components) = -1 Then
        Err.Raise 9, "ModuleName:Let Item: s.Inputs has not been initialised£"
    End If
    s.Components(Index) = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Component(ByVal Index As Long) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    If UBound(s.Components) = -1 Then
        Err.Raise 9, "ModuleName:Get Item: s.Inputs has not been initialised£"
    End If
    Component = s.Components(Index)
End Property


Public Sub SetComponentProperties()

    Dim myPropsWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Set myPropsWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.[_Default]("Component Properties")
    Dim myInputWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Set myInputWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.[_Default]("Input")
    Dim myNonEmptyCells As Long
    myNonEmptyCells = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.[_Default]("Input").Range("D3:D52"))
    ReDim s.Components(myNonEmptyCells)

    Dim j As Long: j = 0

    Dim myInput As Variant
    Dim k As Long: k = 3
    Do Until IsEmpty(myInputWs.Cells.Item(k, 3))


        For Each myInput In s.Components

            Set myInput = New Components

            ' The addition of code to deal with data from myInputWs is left as an exercise for the reader
            myInput.Cas = myInputWs.Cells.Item(k, 3)

            myInput.Concentration = myInputWs.Cells.Item(k, 4)
            myInput.Name = myInputWs.Cells.Item(k, 2)
            myInput.Source_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myInput.Cas, myPropsWs.Range("A3:A1000"), 0)


            myInput.ComponentProperties = myPropsWs.Range(myPropsWs.Cells.Item(myInput.Source_Row, 2), myPropsWs.Cells.Item(myInput.Source_Row, 60)).Value2

        Next

        j = j + 1

    Loop

'    Do
'
'
'        For Each myInput In s.Inputs
'
'            Set myInput = New Components
'            myInputs.Cas = myInputWs.Cells(k, 3)
'            If IsEmpty(myInputWs.Cells(k, 3)) Then
'
'                ' any other needed action before exiting
'                Exit Function
'
'            End If
'            myInput.Concentration = Worksheets("Input").Cells(k, 4)
'            myInput.Name = myInputWs.Cells(k, 2)
'            myInput.Source_Row = Application.Match(myInput.Cas, myPropsWs.Range("A3:A1000"), 0)
'
'            myInput.ComponentProperties = myPropsWs.Range(myPropsWs.Cells(myInputs.Source_Row, 2), myPropsWs.Cells(myInputs.Source_Row, 60)).Value2
'
'        Next
'        ' I've no idea what the line below is doing.
'        j = j + 1
'
'    Loop

End Sub
```

Some code to test the update above.

```
Sub TestComponentsUpdate()

    Dim ThisComponents As Components
    Set ThisComponents = New Components
    ThisComponents.Item(BTU) = 42

    Dim myProperty As Variant
    myProperty = ThisComponents.Item(Amine)

    Dim myItem As ComponentPropertyEnum
    For myItem = ComponentPropertyEnum.AMCRN To ComponentPropertyEnum.VP50_Kpa


        Debug.Print "ComponentProperty Enum:Value", myItem; ":"; ThisComponents.Item(myItem)

    Next

    Dim myProp As Variant
    For Each myProp In ThisComponents.Items

        Debug.Print "ComponentProperty Value", myProp

    Next

    ' The code above was located in Module2 when I updated it,  Replace Module2 with your own Module name
    Dim myProp2 As Variant
    For Each myProp2 In Components(4).Items

        Debug.Print "Components 4 ComponentsProperty  Value", myProp2

    Next

End Sub
```

**The Backing Variable and Enumeration**

The code below assumes that you have access to the code in the Component class.

Add the code below to the code of the component class. The Enum, Type and variable declarations should go before the first sub/function.

This code will allow you to replace the code from

```
.Name = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 2)
to
.Amine = Worksheets("Component Properties").Cells(Inputs(i).Source_Row, 60)
```

with a single line as in the code above.

```
Option Explicit
'Enumerations and Type declarations go before the
' first sub/function in a module or class


Public Enum ComponentProperties
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/enum-statement
     ComponentName
     MW
     VP50_Kpa
     Tki
     L_Den
     mL_mol
     BP
     FP
     Refrigerated
     Pyrophoric
     GUP
     FG
     LG
     FL
     OG
     SC
     EI
     RS
     SS
     GCM
     Carcinogen
     RH
     Store
     STOSE
     EHA
     EHC
     ODS
     Toxicity
     AMCRN
     Tci
     LC50
     S1S
     S2S
     Comp_F
     SL_Hi
     SL_Lo
     Reactive
     BTU
     LEL
     UEL
     MOC
     CF
     KK
     Prop_65
     C_no
     H_no
     O_no
     S_no
     Si_no
     B_no
     N_no
     P_no
     F_no
     Cl_no
     Br_no
     I_no
     Halogen_no
     Silane
     Amine

End Enum

' A user defined Type is used to hold a backing variable
' (otherwise known as private member)

Private Type State

    Data                                As Variant

End Type

Private s                               As State

' The property which allows an array  to be written to or obtained from a Component object
' its assumed that the array will come from a spreadsheet
' e.g. columns 2 to 60 of the Component Properties spreadsheet
' it also means that we can retries the properties as an array so that we can iterate overthem if required.

Public Property Set Data(ByVal PropertiesArray As Variant)
    s.Data = PropertiesArray
End Property


Public Property Get Data() As Variant
    Data = s.Data
End Property


' The Item Property (if Item hasn't already been used in the component object)
' allows reading and writing of individual properties

Public Property Let Item(ByVal Value As Variant, ByVal Index As ComponentProperty)
    s.Data(Index) = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Item(ByVal Index As ComponentProperty) As Variant
    Item = s.Data(Index)
End Property
```

In the original code we don't know what is happening for each of the 58 properties used.  If the properties (such as .Refrigerated) are only storing data and not doing any validation then each property can be replaced by the respective .Item(Enumeration)  e.g. .Item(Refrigerated).

If each property is doing validation before it stores the received value then you will need to implement a pass through property for each property in the Components class.  If this is the case let me know and I'll update the answer.

If you have any questions on the above code then please ask away but really we should move such a discussion to a chat room.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, these days things are getting hectic where I live. But holy moly I am quickly learning how much I don't understand haha. I'm going to have to do some more research and reassess my approach. Thank you so much for going into as much detail as you did. It's a good jumping off point.

Comment: do you have any recommendations for text books to learn this in greater depth?

Comment: There are three steps for which you need to seek tutorials.  1. Understanding VBA. 2. Understanding the excel object model 3. learning how to model in your head how to apply VBA and the Excel office model to solve your particular problem. There are lots of online tutorials , particularly for the VBA/Excel combination.  Strangely enough I don't use Excel so I'm not the best source for a recommendation.

Comment: I was unfortunate in that I am expected to be a programmer when I went for chemistry haha. I do really appreciate your help @freeflow. I think thew first step to learning is knowing what you don't know and the second is knowing where to learn...so I'm on my way I guess. haha

Comment: Programming is no worse that being given an unknown compound and having to work out what it is.  There's a standard set of tests you would run.  Likewise in programming, for every problem, there is a standard set of structures that you can use.   You just need to take a little time and get to grips with the terminology and tools.

Comment: And in another sense its no worse that having to synthesis compound Z, a specific enantiomer of   multiringed stereoisomered behemoth. You start with simpler compunds and build up to the final product.